# How do I remove the intellisense suggestion in vscode?

Tags: visual-studio-code

when I type something like "con" I get a pop up window that suggests multiple possible completions like "console"

I don't want this, I want to write everything on my own with no mini window popping up.

I tried the following solution I found online but it's not working.

In my settings json file:

```
  "editor.suggestOnTriggerCharacters": false,
```

This doesn't work, even after restarting vs code.

This is how my settings json file looks like:

```
    {
  "workbench.colorTheme": "Night Owl (No Italics)",
  "editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode",
  "editor.formatOnSave": true,
  "editor.tokenColorCustomizations": {
    "[Night Owl (No Italics)]": {}
  },
  "window.zoomLevel": 3,
  "workbench.iconTheme": "vscode-icons",
  "terminal.integrated.env.windows": {},
  "editor.inlineSuggest.enabled": false,
  "editor.screenReaderAnnounceInlineSuggestion": false,
  "editor.suggest.showWords": false,
  "editor.suggestOnTriggerCharacters": false,
  "json.schemas": []
}
```

I also ticked off: Editor > inline suggest: Enabled in my settings.

Comment: Search the settings for `quick suggestions`.

Comment: @Mark Yup works, for some reason this was difficult to find. 

Thank you.